# Converting highly complex XML structure to table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, openxml

I have a stored procedure that spits out two columns. One is an ID and the other column is a highly complex XML format for that ID. My requirement is to convert this XML to table format. The XML has 300 nodes and sub nodes. The structure looks like:

```
 <Main>
<Version>1.0</Version>
<CId>459876569</CId>
<Overview>
    <Type>Y</Type>
    <CreateDate>20180505</CreateDate>
    <PlanType>A</PlanType>
    <EffectiveDate>20171201</EffectiveDate>
    <EndDate>20181130</EndDate>
    <Comments>No other comments</Comments>
</Overview>
<EssentialInfo>
    <ContactI>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <MiddleName>A</MiddleName>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <DateOfBirth>19500808</DateOfBirth>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine1>dfsfsdf</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>dsfsdfa</AddressLine2>
            <City>gdfgdfg</City>
        </Address>
        <HomePhone>98745632148</HomePhone>
    </Contact>
  </EssentialInfo>
</Main>
```

I am aware of the OPENXML method but naming the 300 columns make it tedious. Any other method to resolve this?

I am trying to implement [Workflow suggestion - XML & SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896633/workflow-suggestion-xml-sql) this functionality and to do so I am trying to convert my huge XML to SQL table

Comment: can you also post an example of the XML rather than the JSON version of it

Comment: will add it in a minute

Comment: Would you like this to be done via sql or are you open to using post processing via python/java/json etc

Comment: @RobertI question edited. I want to accomplish this in SQL only

Comment: Is there a good reason to convert the XML to a humongous 300-column table? Or asked differently, what's the reason against storing the XML in SQL Server's native XML datatype and using the T-SQL language-native XML-related constructs to work with it? (Related point - it's likely that the data in the XML represents a relational structure and pushing it into a single, non-normalized 300-column table would be the completely wrong thing to do anyway.)

Comment: @Tomalak I am asking this question for a workflow purpose. I have to implement  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896633/workflow-suggestion-xml-sql) this functionality and to do so I am trying to convert my humongous XML to sql table

Comment: The process for converting data to third normal form is taught in every CS course so I'm not sure why you are asking the question. You seem to be hoping that it will produce an answer that isn't humungously complex, but I'm afraid that hope is misplaced; there are very good reasons people prefer to hold this kind of data in XML form rather than in normalized tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If open to a TVF as a helper function, and assuming the XML is to be pivoted to ONE record.

**Clearly** the fully declared SQL would be more performant.

**Example**

```
Declare @XML xml ='
<Main>
<Version>1.0</Version>
<CId>459876569</CId>
<Overview>
    <Type>Y</Type>
    <CreateDate>20180505</CreateDate>
    <PlanType>A</PlanType>
    <EffectiveDate>20171201</EffectiveDate>
    <EndDate>20181130</EndDate>
    <Comments>No other comments</Comments>
</Overview>
<EssentialInfo>
    <Contact>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <MiddleName>A</MiddleName>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <DateOfBirth>19500808</DateOfBirth>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine1>dfsfsdf</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>dsfsdfa</AddressLine2>
            <City>gdfgdfg</City>
        </Address>
        <HomePhone>98745632148</HomePhone>
    </Contact>
  </EssentialInfo>
</Main>
'

Select * Into #Temp from [dbo].[tvf-XML-Hier](@XML) Order by R1

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select Item = concat(Element,IIF(Attribute='''','''',''_''+Attribute))
              ,Value
         From #Temp
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + Stuff((Select ','+QuoteName(concat(Element,IIF(Attribute='','','_'+Attribute))) 
                                                From  #Temp 
                                                Where Value is not null 
                                                Order by R1
                                                For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The TVF if Interested**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-XML-Hier](@XML xml)

Returns Table 
As Return

with  cte0 as ( 
                  Select Lvl       = 1
                        ,ID        = Cast(1 as int) 
                        ,Pt        = Cast(NULL as int)
                        ,Element   = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                        ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(150))
                        ,Value     = x.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')
                        ,XPath     = cast(concat(x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)'),'[' ,cast(Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(max))
                        ,Seq       = cast(1000000+Row_Number() over(Order By (Select 1)) as varchar(max))
                        ,AttData   = x.query('.') 
                        ,XMLData   = x.query('*') 
                  From   @XML.nodes('/*') a(x) 
                  Union  All
                  Select Lvl       = p.Lvl + 1 
                        ,ID        = Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10
                        ,Pt        = p.ID
                        ,Element   = c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                        ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(150))
                        ,Value     = cast( c.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max) ) 
                        ,XPath     = cast(concat(p.XPath,'/',c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)'),'[',cast(Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)') Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(max) )
                        ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10) as varchar(max))
                        ,AttData   = c.query('.') 
                        ,XMLData   = c.query('*') 
                  From   cte0 p 
                  Cross  Apply p.XMLData.nodes('*') b(c) 
              )
    , cte1 as (   
                  Select R1 = Row_Number() over (Order By Seq),A.*
                  From  (
                          Select  Lvl,ID,Pt,Element,Attribute,Value,XPath,Seq From cte0
                          Union All
                          Select Lvl       = p.Lvl+1
                                ,ID        = p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                                ,Pt        = p.ID
                                ,Element   = p.Element
                                ,Attribute = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                                ,Value     = x.value('.','varchar(max)')
                                ,XPath     = p.XPath + '/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')
                                ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) ) as varchar(max))
                          From   cte0 p 
                          Cross  Apply AttData.nodes('/*/@*') a(x) 
                        ) A 
               )

Select A.R1
      ,R2  = IsNull((Select max(R1) From cte1 Where Seq Like A.Seq+'%'),A.R1)
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Element
      ,A.Attribute
      ,A.XPath
      ,Title = Replicate('|---',Lvl-1)+Element+IIF(Attribute='','','@'+Attribute)
      ,A.Value
 From  cte1 A

/*
Source: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10495/xquery-lab-58-select-from-xml.aspx

Declare @XML xml='<person><firstname preferred="Annie" nickname="BeBe">Annabelle</firstname><lastname>Smith</lastname></person>'
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-XML-Hier](@XML) Order by R1
*/
```

**If it helps with the Visualization, the TVF returns**

> Clearly this can be thinned down if you don't need all the columns

[image]

Comment: @Rick Yes, it will parse virtually any XML as illustrated in the "tree" image.  We just apply a dynamic pivot to the results.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful!

Comment: @Rick Always happy to help